# Why does Date.yesterday() return the day before yesterday in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a little bit confused by the `Date.yesterday()`, for example:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.2)
irb(main):001:0> Date.today
=> Fri, 10 Jul 2020
irb(main):002:0> Date.yesterday
=> Wed, 08 Jul 2020
irb(main):003:0> Time.now
=> 2020-07-10 03:54:46.02207138 +0530
irb(main):004:0>
```

[image]

But if I am not wrong, if today is Friday, which is true, the previous day should be Thursday as I learnt in my  primary school..

What's going on in here?

Comment: Likely time zones. [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones) might help.

Comment: Sorry my bad there, the time was set to UTC, but honestly I didn't know that UTC doesn't have Thursdays...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tl;dr: Use `Date.current` and `Time.current` instead of `Date.today` and `Time.now`.

Your application has its own time zone, `Time.zone`. Ruby is not aware of time zones, but Rails is. Rails *partially* updates `Time` and `Date` to be aware of time zones, but not completely. Any methods Rails adds will be time zone aware. [`Date.yesterday`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-tomorrow) and [`Date.tomorrow`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-yesterday), for example. Built-in Ruby methods it leaves alone, like [`Date.today`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today). This [causes some confusion](https://i.imgflip.com/47s5ai.jpg).

`Date.today` is giving today according to your local time zone,  +0530. `Date.yesterday` is giving yesterday according to your application's time zone which I'm guessing is +0000 (UTC). 2020-07-10 03:54:46 +0530 is 2020-07-09 22:24:46 UTC so `Date.yesterday` is 2020-07-08.

Use [`Date.current`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-current) instead of `Date.today`. `Date.yesterday` is a thin wrapper around `Date.current.yesterday`. Similarly, use [`Time.current`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-current) instead of `Time.now`.

The ThoughtBot article [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones) discusses Rails time zones in detail and has simple DOs and DON'Ts to avoid time zone confusion.

DON'T USE

- Time.now
- Date.today
- Date.today.to_time
- Time.parse("2015-07-04 17:05:37")
- Time.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

DO USE

- Time.current
- 2.hours.ago
- Time.zone.today
- Date.current
- 1.day.from_now
- Time.zone.parse("2015-07-04 17:05:37")
- Time.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").in_time_zone

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check the location of the server where the application is running.  The value of `Date.yesterday` will likely depend on the location of the server with respect to the international date line.  For example, while it is still Thursday, 07/09/2020 in New York City, it is Friday, 07/10/2020 in New Zealand.

Comment: My server is the local system, and `Time.now.strftime('%z, %Z')` returns `"+0530, IST"` which is correct.

Comment: @S.Goswami check the value of Time.zone on the machine.  Just curious, what does it return?

Comment: @S.Goswami ```Date.yesterday``` makes use of the time zone set in the ```Date``` class, which might be different from that used in the ```Time``` class.

Comment: It returns `#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x0000562119a83708 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Etc/UTC>>`

Comment: @S.Goswami The current UTC date is 07/09/2020.  That explains the discrepancy.

Comment: @S.Goswami it looks like the ```Time``` class is configured to use ```"+0530, IST"```, whereas the ```Date``` class is configured to use ```UTC```.

Answer (score 1):

In your Rails app, you may have a value set for `Time.zone` or in the configuration for `config.time_zone`.

If one of these values is configured, then Rails uses this as follows:

```rb
def yesterday
  ::Date.current.yesterday
end

def current
  ::Time.zone ? ::Time.zone.today : ::Date.today
end
```

These are ActiveSupport Date helpers

Comment: It's not working as expected, and the output is same as in the question, because the zone is wrong in my case.

Comment: What do you get when you type into the rails console Time.zone.to_s

Comment: I used to get "(GMT+00:00) UTC", but setting the zone to "Kolkata" in my case fixed the issue...

Answer (score 0):

So it's indeed a result of wrong Timezone, in my case  `Time.zone.name` returned `"UTC"`. The correct zone for me is *Asia/Kolkata*, to check the presence of the timezone:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.select { |x| x[/^kol/i] }
```

Which returned `{"Kolkata"=>"Asia/Kolkata"}` in my case.

- For it to take effect temporarily, I set `Time.zone = 'Kolkata'` in the rails console.
- For a permanent effect, added `config.time_zone = 'Kolkata'` to `{project_root}/config/application.rb`.

This fixed the problem, and `Date.yesterday()`, `Date.today()`, and `Date.tomorrow()` are working as expected.

Comment: `Date.today` will only work so long as your application's time zone matches your local one. If your application is put on a server in a different time zone it will break again. Use `Date.current` instead to avoid this problem cropping up again.